# find the xpath of specific label

Tags: xpath

can somebody please tell me what is the best way to get xpath of Links midden label.

```
<div class="subfield even">


    <div class="subfield-item" id="idee1598f081d2b9c6370a9de9b6e54693">

        <span>
            <ul class="radiogroup vertical">
                <li>
                    <input type="radio"  value="radio195" class="wicket-id5d2">
                    <label for="id5b7">Links boven</label>
                </li><li>
                    <input type="radio"  value="radio196" class="wicket-id5d2">
                    <label for="id5b8">Links midden</label>
                </li><li>
                    <input  value="radio197" class="wicket-id5d2">
                    <label for="id5b9">Links onder</label>
                </li><li>
</li>
</ul>
</span>
```

Comment: What do you mean?  You want the xml for the <label> element that contains the text value of "Links midden"?  Your example is not valid XML.

Comment: i want to navigate to links midden label using xpath

Comment: //div[@class='subfield even']//div[@class='subfield-item']//lu[@class='radiogroup vertical']/li/label[contains (text(),'Lins midden')] something like that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//li/label[@for='id5b8']
```

Depends on how specific you want to get. This will break if your id changes.

If that is the case, try not using the @for attribute.

Also, consider CSS Selectors instead, they are usually more robust to changes, or at least are easier to make them that way

You can also develop/test your xpath using browser tools or online tools like this 
http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: Could you explain why you wrote `//li/label` instead `//label` ?